# raty and jQuery.noConflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, raty

I'm trying to integrate raty to running webapplication.
For several reasons jquery is used with jQuery.noConflict. In this case $ is replaced by $j.
The thing is I can't get it work with this $j. 
Here's what I'm doing (I have noticed that it's partly works when I set readonly: true)

```
$j(document).ready(function () {

            $j('#divraty').raty({                
                path: '/images/raty',
                score: 4,
                click: function (score, evt) {
                    alert('ID: ' + $j(this).attr('id') + "\nscore: " + score + "\nevent: " + evt);
                }
            });
}
```

I have noticed that it's partly works when I set readonly: true (the 4 stars are showed and no error in the console)

Here's what the console says: Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'on'

I try replacing all $ by $j in the jquery.raty.js but it doesn't change anything.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: which jquery version is used

Comment: there is no need to replace `$` in jquery.raty.js, it handles it internally

Comment: you need to use jquery >= 1.7 since raty uses `.on()`

Comment: Damn!!!! I thought I was using the latest jquery... but I wasn't... thanx

Comment: Also there is no need to modify jquery.raty.js file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use jQuery >= 1.7 since [raty](http://wbotelhos.com/raty/) plugin uses [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Also there is no need to modify `jquery.raty.js` file since it handles the noConflict internally